# Fusion Charts vertical axis labels

Tags: customization, axis-labels, fusioncharts, yaxis

I'm trying to characterize the values on the vertical axis, labeling them as text. For example, a value of 25 would be "Low", 50 would be "Medium" and 75 would be "High". I don't see anywhere in the documentation that that can be done. The following graph would be my desired result:

Risk Assessment

[image: 1]

In fact, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this in either Excel or Google Sheets (unless I'm missing something).

Any help would be appreciated.

I searched the documentation and found nothing to help solve my problem. I also researched Excel and Google sheets but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged fusioncharts, yes you can achieve with annotations object in fusioncharts - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/annotations/real-life-use-cases#provide-more-information-about-data-plots

A quick look at the object would be like this -

```
 "annotations": {
    "origw": "600",
    "origh": "450",
    "autoscale": "1",
    "groups": [{
        "id": "ds1tips",
        "items": [{
            "id": "indicator-line",
            "type": "line",
            "dashed": "1"
        }, {
            "id": "tip1_1",
            "type": "rectangle",
            "fillcolor": "#6baa01",
            "x": "$dataset.0.set.0.x + 5",
            "y": "$dataset.0.set.0.y - 30",
            "tox": "$dataset.0.set.0.x + 80",
            "toy": "$dataset.0.set.0.y - 10",
            "visible": "0"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "yaxisline",
        "items": [{
            "id": "line",
            "type": "line",
            "color": "#f8bd19",
            "x": "$canvasstartx - 5",
            "y": "$canvasstarty",
            "tox": "$canvasstartx - 5",
            "toy": "$canvasendy",
            "thickness": "3"
        }, {
            "id": "none-label-bg",
            "type": "rectangle",
            "fillcolor": "#f8bd19",
            "x": "$canvasstartx - 60",
            "tox": "$canvasstartx - 15",
            "y": "$canvasendy - 20",
            "toy": "$canvasendy",
            "radius": "3"
        }, {
            "id": "none-dot",
            "type": "circle",
            "radius": "5",
            "x": "$canvasstartx - 5",
            "y": "$canvasendy - 10",
            "color": "#f8bd19"
        }, {
            "id": "none-label",
            "type": "text",
            "fillcolor": "#ffffff",
            "text": "None",
            "x": "$canvasstartx - 37",
            "y": "$canvasendy - 12",
            "fontsize": "12",
            "bold": "1"
        }, {
            "id": "few-label-bg",
            "type": "rectangle",
            "fillcolor": "#f8bd19",
            "x": "$canvasstartx - 55",
            "tox": "$canvasstartx - 15",
            "y": "$canvasendy - 100",
            "toy": "$canvasendy - 80",
            "radius": "3"
        }, {
            "id": "few-dot",
            "type": "circle",
            "radius": "5",
            "x": "$canvasstartx - 5",
            "y": "$canvasendy - 90",
            "color": "#f8bd19"
        }, {
            "id": "few-label",
            "type": "text",
            "fillcolor": "#ffffff",
            "text": "Few",
            "x": "$canvasstartx - 35",
            "y": "$canvasendy - 92",
            "fontsize": "12",
            "bold": "1"
        }, {
            "id": "moderate-label-bg",
            "type": "rectangle",
            "fillcolor": "#f8bd19",
            "x": "$canvasstartx - 85",
            "tox": "$canvasstartx - 15",
            "y": "$canvasendy - 180",
            "toy": "$canvasendy - 160",
            "radius": "3"
        }, {
            "id": "moderate-dot",
            "type": "circle",
            "radius": "5",
            "x": "$canvasstartx - 5",
            "y": "$canvasendy - 170",
            "color": "#f8bd19"
        }, {
            "id": "moderate-label",
            "type": "text",
            "fillcolor": "#ffffff",
            "text": "Moderate",
            "x": "$canvasstartx - 50",
            "y": "$canvasendy - 172",
            "fontsize": "12",
            "bold": "1"
        }, {
            "id": "maximum-label-bg",
            "type": "rectangle",
            "fillcolor": "#f8bd19",
            "x": "$canvasstartx - 88",
            "tox": "$canvasstartx - 15",
            "y": "$canvasendy - 260",
            "toy": "$canvasendy - 240",
            "radius": "3"
        }, {
            "id": "maximum-dot",
            "type": "circle",
            "radius": "5",
            "x": "$canvasstartx - 5",
            "y": "$canvasendy - 252",
            "color": "#f8bd19"
        }, {
            "id": "maximum-label",
            "type": "text",
            "fillcolor": "#ffffff",
            "text": "High",
            "x": "$canvasstartx - 52",
            "y": "$canvasendy - 252",
            "fontsize": "12",
            "bold": "1"
        }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it in fusion chart using annotations -

```
    {
    "chart": {
        "caption": "Number of visitors last week",
        "subCaption": "Bakersfield Central vs Los Angeles Topanga",
        "xAxisName": "Day",
        "yAxisName": "No. of visitors",
        "yAxisNamePadding": "100",
        "showYAxisValues": "0",
        "theme": "fusion",
        "showValues": "0",
        "showTooltip": "0"
    },
    "categories": [{
        "category": [{
            "label": "Mon"
        }, {
            "label": "Tue"
        }, {
            "label": "Wed"
        }, {
            "vline": "true",
            "lineposition": "0",
            "color": "#6baa01",
            "labelHAlign": "right",
            "labelPosition": "0",
            "label": "National holiday"
        }, {
            "label": "Thu"
        }, {
            "label": "Fri"
        }, {
            "label": "Sat"
        }, {
            "label": "Sun"
        }]
    }],
    "annotations": {
        "origw": "600",
        "origh": "450",
        "autoscale": "1",
        "groups": [{
            "id": "ds1tips",
            "items": [{
                "id": "indicator-line",
                "type": "line",
                "dashed": "1"
            }, {
                "id": "tip1_1",
                "type": "rectangle",
                "fillcolor": "#6baa01",
                "x": "$dataset.0.set.0.x + 5",
                "y": "$dataset.0.set.0.y - 30",
                "tox": "$dataset.0.set.0.x + 80",
                "toy": "$dataset.0.set.0.y - 10",
                "visible": "0"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": "yaxisline",
            "items": [{
                "id": "line",
                "type": "line",
                "color": "#f8bd19",
                "x": "$canvasstartx - 5",
                "y": "$canvasstarty",
                "tox": "$canvasstartx - 5",
                "toy": "$canvasendy",
                "thickness": "3"
            }, {
                "id": "none-label-bg",
                "type": "rectangle",
                "fillcolor": "#f8bd19",
                "x": "$canvasstartx - 60",
                "tox": "$canvasstartx - 15",
                "y": "$canvasendy - 20",
                "toy": "$canvasendy",
                "radius": "3"
            }, {
                "id": "none-dot",
                "type": "circle",
                "radius": "5",
                "x": "$canvasstartx - 5",
                "y": "$canvasendy - 10",
                "color": "#f8bd19"
            }, {
                "id": "none-label",
                "type": "text",
                "fillcolor": "#ffffff",
                "text": "None",
                "x": "$canvasstartx - 37",
                "y": "$canvasendy - 12",
                "fontsize": "12",
                "bold": "1"
            }, {
                "id": "few-label-bg",
                "type": "rectangle",
                "fillcolor": "#f8bd19",
                "x": "$canvasstartx - 55",
                "tox": "$canvasstartx - 15",
                "y": "$canvasendy - 100",
                "toy": "$canvasendy - 80",
                "radius": "3"
            }, {
                "id": "few-dot",
                "type": "circle",
                "radius": "5",
                "x": "$canvasstartx - 5",
                "y": "$canvasendy - 90",
                "color": "#f8bd19"
            }, {
                "id": "few-label",
                "type": "text",
                "fillcolor": "#ffffff",
                "text": "Few",
                "x": "$canvasstartx - 35",
                "y": "$canvasendy - 92",
                "fontsize": "12",
                "bold": "1"
            }, {
                "id": "moderate-label-bg",
                "type": "rectangle",
                "fillcolor": "#f8bd19",
                "x": "$canvasstartx - 85",
                "tox": "$canvasstartx - 15",
                "y": "$canvasendy - 180",
                "toy": "$canvasendy - 160",
                "radius": "3"
            }, {
                "id": "moderate-dot",
                "type": "circle",
                "radius": "5",
                "x": "$canvasstartx - 5",
                "y": "$canvasendy - 170",
                "color": "#f8bd19"
            }, {
                "id": "moderate-label",
                "type": "text",
                "fillcolor": "#ffffff",
                "text": "Moderate",
                "x": "$canvasstartx - 50",
                "y": "$canvasendy - 172",
                "fontsize": "12",
                "bold": "1"
            }, {
                "id": "maximum-label-bg",
                "type": "rectangle",
                "fillcolor": "#f8bd19",
                "x": "$canvasstartx - 88",
                "tox": "$canvasstartx - 15",
                "y": "$canvasendy - 260",
                "toy": "$canvasendy - 240",
                "radius": "3"
            }, {
                "id": "maximum-dot",
                "type": "circle",
                "radius": "5",
                "x": "$canvasstartx - 5",
                "y": "$canvasendy - 252",
                "color": "#f8bd19"
            }, {
                "id": "maximum-label",
                "type": "text",
                "fillcolor": "#ffffff",
                "text": "High",
                "x": "$canvasstartx - 52",
                "y": "$canvasendy - 252",
                "fontsize": "12",
                "bold": "1"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": "dyn-label-grp",
            "items": [{
                "id": "dyn-label-bg",
                "type": "rectangle",
                "radius": "3"
            }, {
                "id": "dyn-label",
                "type": "text",
                "fillcolor": "#ffffff",
                "fontsize": "12",
                "bold": "1"
            }, {
                "id": "dyn-detail-label",
                "type": "text",
                "align": "right",
                "x": "$canvasendx",
                "bgcolor": "#ffffff"
            }]
        }]
    },
    "dataset": [{
        "seriesname": "Bakersfield Central",
        "data": [{
            "value": "15123"
        }, {
            "value": "14233"
        }, {
            "value": "25507"
        }, {
            "value": "9110"
        }, {
            "value": "15529"
        }, {
            "value": "20803"
        }, {
            "value": "19202"
        }]
    }, {
        "seriesname": "Los Angeles Topanga",
        "data": [{
            "value": "13400"
        }, {
            "value": "12800"
        }, {
            "value": "22800"
        }, {
            "value": "12400"
        }, {
            "value": "15800"
        }, {
            "value": "19800"
        }, {
            "value": "21800"
        }]
    }]
}
```

To know more about it please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/annotations/real-life-use-cases#provide-more-information-about-data-plots

Here is a demo fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/r4fzh3vs/